# How to automatically add a sender to a DocuSign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign to get some documents signed by users.

I'm using the Java SDK and embedded signing to create an envelope, create a recipient view, and return that to the user for signing. After signing is done, I receive a Connect webhook request with the envelope ID. At this point I need to go download the contents of the documents (with the signatures now) to send to a third party. I intend to do this using an admin account and JWT authentication.

However on doing this, I get this error -

```
{
    "errorCode":"USER_NOT_ENVELOPE_SENDER_OR_RECIPIENT",
    "message":"This user is not the sender or a recipient of the envelope.  Only the sender or a recipient of the envelope may perform the requested operation."
}
```

Seemingly, I need my admin account to either be a Recipient or Sender of the envelope to pick these up.

The logical solution seems to be to add the admin as the sender. I tried doing that through the API, but the sender object seems to be overwritten with the recipient's data. I know I can create a "Sender View", but that seems to require manual intervention to click the send button, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there any way to automatically pull in a user's envelope from an admin account without manual intervention?

This seems to be more of a DocuSign paradigm question than a technical one, but of course it might just be that I'm building my requests wrong - I can provide code examples if it would help.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I figured it out. I was creating the envelope/recipient view with the signer's account ID (pulled in through the API) rather than the admin's account ID.

I did this because I was previously getting the error "USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT" on creating an envelope. And this error was because I was trying to create an envelope with the admin's account ID while using the signer's auth token.

So my root cause was that I was trying to create an envelope/recipient view with a signer's auth token rather than creating the auth token with the admin account, which causes the admin to have no access to the envelope.

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of the following things:

1. [Share the envelope](https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/View-Shared-Envelopes?language=en_US&rsc_301) with the (admin?) user that make the API call.
2. Use [JWT with impersonation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) to impersonate the user that sent this envelope. The user will have to consent (once) to an app using their credentials.
3. Use JWT with impersonation to send the envelope as the admin user that will be used later.
4. Add the admin user as a CC of the envelope